# Bootstrap | URL with hash breaks styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Bootstrap-project with some anchors-links. After clicking them my css doesn't work anymore.

HTML:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#SectionID">GoToSection</a>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 id="SectionID">Section With ID</h3>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron::before {
margin-top: -13.4505%;
top: 0;
transform: rotate(-7.73deg);
transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
}    
.jumbotron::before, .jumbotron::after {
background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
content: " ";
display: block;
height: 0;
padding-top: 13.4505%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: 100.917%;
}
*::before, *::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jumbotron::after {
top: 100%;
transform: rotate(7.73deg);
transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
}

.jumbotron {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

You can see it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4GzK/18/).

Afer clicking on 'GoToSelection' the .jumbotron looses it's padding-top. When I disable and then enable the property with firebug it woks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with CSS or HTML.
The jumbotron is not loosing its padding either. What's actually happening here is that. when you click on the link "GoToSection" which has a href value "#SectionID", it is actually scrolling to the
`<h3 id="SectionID">Section With ID</h3>` .